# how to displaydomain value in gsp

Tags: grails, groovy

I have three domain class

```
class Stock
{
   Product product
}
```

and

```
class Product
{
   ProductName productName
}
```

and

```
class ProductName
{
   String name
}
```

In create.gsp of Stock domain, this is the default code generation:-

```
<tr class="prop">
  <td valign="top" class="name">
    <label for="name">
      <g:message code="stock.name.label" default="Product Name" />
    </label>
  </td>
  <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: stockInstance, field: 'name', 'errors')}">
    <g:select name="product.id"
              from="${com.ten.hp.his.pharmacy.Product.list()}"
              optionKey="id"
              optionValue="productName"
              value="${stockInstance?.product?.id}"  />
  </td>
</tr>
```

my requirement is to display the product name in the drop down but by using optionValue, it is showing `productName` id like, `com.ten.ProductName:1`. how can i show, product name in the drop down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jigar answer is correct based on your data model.  The grails select tag expects the optionValue to be the name of the bean property of your element (Product).  The select tag will call toString() on that value so to work with this you need to override the toString() method of the ProductName class.

It is also possible to specify within the gsp that you want the "name" property of the ProductName by passing a closure code as the optionValue.

```
optionValue="${{it.productName.name}}"
```

Answer (score 2):

override `toString()` in class `ProductName` to return just `productName`

like

```
class ProductName
{
   String name

   @Override
   public String toString(){ return name } 
}
```

Comment: thnks, but can't we do something in create.gsp page to display product name?

Comment: Not sure try with `optionValue="productName.name"`

Comment: it is showing exception like this:- No such property: productName.name for class: com.ten.hp.his.pharmacy.Product

Comment: Try with `optionValue="${{it.produceName.name}}"`